# How can we know that an event generated with keybd_event has been recieved/processed by a window /application

Tags: winapi

I m generating some keyboard events on my application using keybd_event().
But I want to check that my application actually got my previous KEYDOWN and KEYUP before i do next set of keydown and keyup (for synchrnization ) Is there any api that will let me know that the  my application has actually recieved /processed the event.

thanks and advance

Answer (score 0):

Hook the wndproc of the app using [SetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898(VS.85).aspx) and check the incoming messages then pass them on to the origional wndproc, this is pretty messay though, but its probably the only non-'black magic' way

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Necrolis.. I tried this .. but I used SetWindowsHookEx for WH_GETMESSAGE , and I see that the application is getting this event (the characters prints there) but I still dont get that notification.. and some times neither my hook gets it nor the application..

Comment: If your targeting a specific windows based application, it might be better to use SendMessage( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx ), see if that solves anything. also try monitoring the actual WNDProc with WH_CALLWNDPROC if you are still using SetWindowHookEx(you can double check the results using Spy++)

Comment: Strangely , when I use spy++ to monitory keyboard messages .. i dont see any message when i do things like "Alt+F" on this window.

Comment: Could that be the reason why even my window hook is not recieving the events?  I am not sure why spy++ or my hook (i.e SetWindowHookEx for WH_GETMESSAGE) is not able to get events/messages when I do any keyboard action with application window.